# How to get last hour data mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get last hour data from mysql table . How to implement query for same .

Comment: What have you attempted so far? It is not recommended to copy your question title and post it to the body.

Comment: Please show us your table structure too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from mytimeTable where timeCol >= DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
```